# How to get in a class variable the actual size of my WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to get in my class a variable double in which i want the actual width of my window, even resized.

I don't want to declare the var in the Window event SizeChanged because it will limit the scope of the var actualWidth to the event SizeChanged.

My problem is the scope of the variable. I want to use it where i want it's why i would like to declare it in the class.

```
   namespace test
   {
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       double actualWidth = ?;  //i don't know what to do 

     public MainWindow()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              .
              . //use actualWidth here if i want
              .
          }

     private void xx()
          {

           //use it here...

          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a field at class-level, just use that instead of a local variable in the eventhandler

```
    //field for width
    double actualWidth;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        //attach an eventhandler
        this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;

        InitializeComponent();
      }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set the fields value
        actualWidth = e.NewSize.Width;
    }

    private void xx()
    {
        //use the fields value for whatever...
        MessageBox.Show(actualWidth.ToString());

    }
```

Or just use the existing property `ActualWidth', no need for an extra field or eventhandler

```
    private void xx()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ActualWidth.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the existing `ActualWidth`?

Comment: Thank you, thanks to that, i understand better how to subscribe to an event a method with the same parameters (i think) but why somebody downvoted my post ?...